# Using JS GraphQL Plugin with makeExecutableSchema

Tags: graphql, webstorm

I am writing a web app in WebStorm based on GraphQL. The web app is comprised of two components (i.e. frontend and backend). On the backend, I am using makeExecutableSchema to create multiple schemas and then merging them together to help maintain my code.

The frontend relies on a WebStorm plugin called JS GraphQL that helps interpret GraphQL mutations and queries as described [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2019/04/featured-plugin-js-graphql/). The plugin expects to see a .graphql file to understand typedefs. I can manually copy/paste information from the backend to the frontend directories. Ideally, I would automatically generate the .graphql file for the frontend during the backend coding. Does anyone have insight on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [graphql-code-generator](https://graphql-code-generator.com/)? It has a plugin architecture and so can be adapted to a variety of needs. I've been on teams that have used it successfully on a few projects, and it's not hard to hook up to CI or whatever.

Comment: I researched this option. The documentation was more focused on reading schema.graphql files to help generate Type files with TS and JSON extensions, which is not what I needed. I would welcome a tutorial on how to automate a solution with graphql-code-generator. I was unable to locate the proper documentation / tuturial. I was able to resolve my issue by downloading the schema from within the GraphQL playground.